# How to construct functions so I don't get conflicts?

Tags: elixir

For example, I want to have a function that can be called like this:

```
foo :bar, key: "value" do
  "some block value"
end
```

or

```
foo key: "value" do
  "some block value"
end
```

or

```
foo :bar do
  "some block value"
end
```

or simply

```
foo key: "value"
```

To start with, function definition looks something like this:

```
def foo(bar, opts \\ [], [do: block])
```

The moment I need to accommodate case where I just pass options but not the :bar, I get compile error. I totally understand why though (`opts \\ []` creates more functions that match my other function definition). So, what's the good work-around to somewhat allow for for that `foo` method to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd define the various possibilities as separate arity functions which call one `do_foo/3` function with the 3 values. Assuming `bar` is never a list (if it can be a list this whole thing becomes ambiguous for arity 1 and 2 because we can't know whether the value is for `bar` or `opts`) you can do something like:

```
defmodule A do
  def foo(opts) when is_list(opts), do: do_foo(nil, opts, nil)
  def foo(bar), do: do_foo(bar, nil, nil)
  def foo(opts, [do: block]) when is_list(opts), do: do_foo(nil, opts, block)
  def foo(bar, [do: block]), do: do_foo(bar, nil, block)
  def foo(bar, opts, [do: block]), do: do_foo(bar, opts, block)

  defp do_foo(bar, opts, block) do
    IO.inspect {bar, opts, block}
  end
end

A.foo :bar, key: "value" do
  "some block value"
end

A.foo key: "value" do
  "some block value"
end

A.foo :bar do
  "some block value"
end

A.foo key: "value"
```

Output:

```
{:bar, [key: "value"], "some block value"}
{nil, [key: "value"], "some block value"}
{:bar, nil, "some block value"}
{nil, [key: "value"], nil}
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Didn't think about making secondary non-ambiguous function. Thanks!